# Looking to calculate stock price difference averages based on shifting criteria more quickly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to conveniently calculate stock price industry averages (IndustryReturn) based on single-company earnings release dates. See table below:

| CompanyName | StockTicker | Q322EarningsDate | Q422EarningsDate | Q322EDStockPrice | Q422EDStockPrice | Return | IndustryReturn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nvidia | NVDA | 11/16/2022 | 2/22/2023 | 159.10 | 207.54 | 30.45% | AVG(AMD+CRUS) |
| AMD | AMD | 11/1/2022 | 1/31/2023 | 59.66 | 75.15 | 25.96% | AVG(NVDA+CRUS) |
| Cirrus Logic | CRUS | 11/1/2022 | 2/2/2023 | 67.85 | 94.89 | 39.85% | AVG(NVDA+AMD) |

Using the first row as an example, if Nvidia's earnings dates are 11/16/2022 and 2/22/2023, I want to take an average of 15 or so other semiconductor companies' stock returns during that period and use the info to fill in the IndustryReturn column. So using the first line in the table above, I would do (AMD stock price 2/22/23 - AMD stock price 11/16/22)/AMD stock price 11/16/22, and then do the same for Cirrus Logic and average the two results. I did this for each line in a separate Excel table, but I'm using Excel's AVERAGE function and need to find a quicker and more scalable way to do this. Intuitively, I think SQL or Pandas can help with this.

I also have a CSV file with the following table setup:

| StockTicker | Date | ClosePrice | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NVDA | 2/28/22 | 243.850006 | 47731900 |
| NVDA | 3/1/22 | 234.770004 | 41205600 |
| NVDA | 3/2/22 | 242.199997 | 38964200 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| AMD | 2/28/22 | 123.339996 | 124666100 |
| AMD | 3/1/22 | 113.830002 | 126552200 |
| AMD | 3/2/22 | 118.279999 | 118354500 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The dates extend until about 2/27/23 in the actual dataset (a year's worth of data).

I wrote the following code to get the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame for analysis:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('Stock Data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df = df.set_index('Stock Ticker')
print(df)
```

And got the following results:

```
                 Date       Close     Volume
Stock Ticker                                
AVGO          2/28/22  587.440002  2500500.0
AVGO           3/1/22  570.119995  2489800.0
AVGO           3/2/22  585.780029  2177100.0
AVGO           3/3/22  578.599976  2645400.0
AVGO           3/4/22  595.989990  4475700.0
...               ...         ...        ...
TXN           2/21/23  170.759995  7030300.0
TXN           2/22/23  169.800003  4577400.0
TXN           2/23/23  171.820007  4856600.0
TXN           2/24/23  169.139999  4118300.0
TXN           2/27/23  170.740005  3204318.0
```

I then added a df.loc() function specifying a date and stock ticker, and the result was a column of boolean values:

```
df.loc['NVDA'],df['Date'] == '2/28/22'
```

```
[251 rows x 3 columns] Stock Ticker
AVGO     True
AVGO    False
AVGO    False
AVGO    False
AVGO    False
        ...  
TXN     False
TXN     False
TXN     False
TXN     False
TXN     False
Name: Date, Length: 2511, dtype: bool
```

I'm wondering how I can have the program locate two values based on the Earnings Date criteria I feed it from the very first table so I don't have to manually search for values for these averages. I came across psycopg2 and am wondering if SQL would be better suited for this issue.